# In magento how to access disabled categories through url

Tags: category

I need to create a category and make it as disable(This category should not visible in front end anywhere) but i want to access that category page through it s Url.Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Do the following during category edit:

```
Include in Navigation Menu : No
Is Active : Yes
```

With the above the category will not display in navigation menu on frontend and you can access it through URL.